# Why are some HTML elements grayed out in Developer Tools?

Tags: html, developer-tools

I have been working a little with HTML, but I can’t figure out why the developer tools are making certain elements gray. Any help would be nice.

[image: html tags]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Developer Tools grays out any non-visible elements. So, for example, the `<head>`, `<meta>`, and `<title>` tags are all grayed out, since they are not actually visible to the user. Similarly, an element with `display: none` will be grayed out. It's nothing to worry about—the browser is simply trying to be helpful.

Comment: Oh, thanks, that’s really helpful. Follow up question: is there a way to use window.setinterval without the browser interfering with it?

Comment: @JohnWalthall I'm not sure what you mean exactly. I'd recommend that you [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

The meta tag should be in the head

Comment: That is true, but this doesn't answer the question OP asked.

Comment: This should be a comment, and nice catch